# a problem of domain and calculus

Tags: real-analysis

I have to find the domain of this funtion
$\sqrt{1+ \frac{4xy}{x^2+y^2}}$

and my answer is $x \ge(-2+\sqrt{3})y  \lor x \le(-2-\sqrt{3})y$

but the suggested solution is  $(2-\sqrt{3})|y| \le |x| \le(2+\sqrt{3})|y|$

Supposing that my answer is correct how can I pass from one form to the other?

Comment: Split you answer in two cases: $x\ge 0$ and $x\lt 0$

Comment: @Andrei in  which sense?

Answer (score 0):

$(x,y)=(2,1)$ satisfies the solution given, but yours does not. This means you only have a partial solution, and your answer is not equivalent to the solution given.

In fact, you have exactly half of the solution: 
[image]

Your solution is below the red line and above the blue, so is only valid for $x\le 0$. The actual solution is: 
[image]
between these lines. Your region for $x\le0$ is the same, but you are missing the $x>0$ case, as noted in a comment.

Comment: if x=2 and y=1 my solution is satisfied because $2 \ge -2+\sqrt{3}$

Comment: could you explain it without graphs and with only analitical passages?

Comment: @Anne Ah yes, but then in that case, your solution includes $(x,y)=(-4,20)$, but this does not solve the given solution. Also I find that graphs help to visualise this kind of problem well, by sketching the regions and seeing the answer. If you wanted to do this analytically, I would suggest taking the different cases $x\ge0$ and $x<0$ and expanding.

Comment: is my domain correct?

Comment: @Anne If you changed the $\lor$ into a $\land$, then it produces half of the correct answer (the left had side region in the 2nd graph I have plotted.

Comment: excuse me but is it possible to have some hints about what to do analitically?

Comment: is my calculation for the domain correct?